# Scala calculator that accepts three string parameters

Tags: scala, functional-programming

How to write a method called calculator that accepts three string parameters:

```
def calculator(operand1: String, operator: String, operand2: String): Unit
```

Converts the operands to Int;
Performs the desired mathematical operator (+, -, *, or /) on the two operands
Prints the result, or a generic error messages

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This site rewards effort. What have you tried so far? Show us code that didn't work so we can better address your understanding of the Scala language.

Answer (score 2):

Your question shows that you put little to no effort into finding the solution yourself.

When asking a question on StackOverflow next time, ask a question about existing code (e.g. "Why am I getting this exception?" or "Why doesn't my code compile?") and don't assume some internet code monkey will magically write your code.

---

Anyways, as you seem to be a new member of SO, `def calculator` would look something like this:

```
import scala.collection.immutable.StringOps._
import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}

def calculator(left: String, op: String, right: String): Unit = {

  def parse(value: String) = Try(value.toDouble)

  (parse(left), parse(right)) match {
    case (Success(leftDouble), Success(rightDouble)) => {
      op match {
        case "/" => println(leftDouble / rightDouble)
        case "*" => println(leftDouble * rightDouble)
        case "+" => println(leftDouble + rightDouble)
        case "-" => println(leftDouble - rightDouble)
        case invalid: String => println(s"Invalid operator $invalid.")
      }
    }
    case (Failure(e), _) => println(s"Could not parse $left.")
    case(_, Failure(e)) => println(s"Could not parse $right.")
    case(Failure(e1), Failure(e2)) => println(s"Could not parse $left and $right.")
  }

}
```

[Try it out!](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/UwVBmC8/2)

If you need any explanation don't hesitate to drop a comment.

I hope this helps.